Action of profinite groups on primes
Let $G = \varprojlim G_i$ be a profinite group, $A$ a commutative ring with a $G$-action. Suppose furthermore that $A = \bigcup A^{U_i}$, where $U_i$ range over the open normal subgroups of $G$. Is it true that, for each prime $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(A^G)$, $G$ acts transitively on the set of primes of $A$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$?
I am aware that this holds when $G$ is finite, but am not sure how to (if possible) to extend it to the profinite case. I am particularly interested in the case that $G = \operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$, where $L/K$ is a (possibly infinite) Galois extension, $B$ is a $k$-algebra, and $A = B \otimes_k L$, so that $B = A^G$. Note that I am not assuming that $A$ is finitely generated, an integral domain, Noetherian, etc.

In the appendix on infinite Galois theory and ramification theory in Washington's Introduction to cyclotomic fields, this is proved when $K$ is a number field and $A$ and $B$ are the integers in $K$ and $L$, by applying the known finite case and passage to a convergent subsequence (using compactness of the Galois group).  Look at that argument as a template, perhaps using subnets in place of subsequences.

I see—essentially the same proof works but by replacing nets instead of sequences since $L/K$ may be uncountable. Thank you for the reference.
